# I have one login template and I want to pass "Invalid credentials" message with that template in Django

Tags: html, django

I am using following code for rendering "login.html" with "context" and send message to the template but it is not working.

```
 messages.warning(request, 'Wrong Credentials.')
 return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login') )
```

---

**views.py:**

```
       from django.contrib import messages
       from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
       from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
       if access_token:
           "do something"
       else:
           messages.error(request,"Wrong credentials")
           return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(login))
```

**login.html:**

```
          {% if messages %}
            {% for msg in messages %}
                  <div class="alert alert-{{msg.tags}} page-alert" style="text-align:center">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss='alert'><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                 {{msg}}
                  </div>
            {% endfor %}
          {% endif %}
```

Comment: have you went over the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/messages/)?

Comment: If you have a login form, it is usually better to redisplay the form with errors instead of redirecting. Django comes with login forms and views. I would consider using these instead of writing your own.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a message, it is stored using whichever [storage backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/messages/#storage-backends) you are using. The default `FallbackStorage` backend stores the message in a cookie or the session.

Therefore you don't need to include any context when you try to redirect to a new URL. You can change your code to:

```
messages.warning(request, 'Wrong Credentials.')  # No need to assign result to a variable
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login') )
```

You can simplify this using the `redirect` shortcut:

```
from django.shortcut import redirect

messages.warning(request, 'Wrong Credentials.')
return redirect('login')
```

Comment: I want to redirect on login page. That is working with above code but I also want to popup or display one message with that redirection. How can I do that?

Comment: You need to update your login template or base template to include the messages. The [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/messages/#displaying-messages) show you how.  You should remove the context from the return statement as I suggested. Even if it doesn't give you an error, it doesn't make sense to do that.

Comment: I want that template because when user entered wrong credentials then above code will redirect to login template but I want to show you the message to the user that he/she entered wrong credentials because I am using custom authentication not default one. So user needs to know that he/she entered wrong credentials. I don't want user to redirect to login page without any message.

Comment: As I said, you need to update your login template or base template to include the messages.

Comment: I am getting "none" value in above "messages.warning(request, 'Wrong Credentials.')" response. Though I properly add code in template as well as in view.

Comment: As I said yesterday, `messages.warning()` stores the message using the storage backend. You do not need to use the return value of `messages.warning()`. Just redirect to the next view, then display the messages in the template. I can't help you with any issues on the login view/template because you haven't included them in your question.

Comment: views.py:
                 messages.error(request,"Wrong Credentials.")
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login'))                                   login.html::                                                                                              {% if messages %}{% for msg in messages %}<div class="alert alert-{{msg.tags}} page-alert" style="text-align:center"> <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss='alert'><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button> {{msg}}</div>{% endfor %}{% endif %}

Comment: Don't put code in the comments, it's unreadable. Put it in your answer as I asked.

Comment: Just check I provided my code in answer. I just want to know where I am doing mistake

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the code you have shown. Perhaps you are including it in the wrong place in your template, or the problem is in the login view.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add arguments to `reverse`, use it like this

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login',kwargs={'key','value'}))
# the kwargs arguments should be set up in your url patterns
```

But in your case, I am not sure it's what you want. You don't need to redirect to the url with arguments. Just use `HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login'))` or better, with `redirect('login_name')` where login_name is the name of your url.

**Send messages to templates**

```
messages.warning(request, 'Wrong Credentials.')
# another way
messages.add_message(request,messages.WARNING,'Wrong Credentials.',extra_tags='more_tags_here')
```

**Get messages from templates** [more info](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/messages/#django.contrib.messages.get_messages)

Designed with bootstrap

```
{% if messages %}
    {% for msg in messages %}
        <div class="alert alert-{{msg.tags}} page-alert" style="text-align:center">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss='alert'><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
            {{msg}}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: In views.py I wrote following code:                                                          if access_token { "do this " } else {               messages.success(request,"Wrong Credentials")                                         return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login'))}

Comment: I am getting none value in message.error(request,"Wrong") in this

Comment: did you try this instead: `messages.add_message(request,messages.WARNING,'Wrong Credentials.'`. What did you get in this : `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(login))`

Comment: Yes ,I tried "messages.add_message(request,messages.WARNING,'Wrong Credentials.')" also but it didn't work. For "return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(login))" this I am getting login template with no "wrong credentials" message printed on it.

Comment: can you edit your question with what your codes look right now

Comment: I edited my code above. You can check now Lemayzeur and let me know if it needs any modification.

Comment: You got none value for `message`, I need to take a look at your current codes, so please an update with the whole codes of the view